# java 8k limit on text files

Tags: java

I'm new at java.  I have a 12k ".TXT" file that I'm reading into a String array - no problem.
I want to now output that String array to a new ".TXT" file.  There seems to be an 8k limit on output to a ".TXT" file.  How do I c

Comment: You just need to f :-)

Comment: No there is not. How exactly are you doing it? I suggest you use a library like Apache Commons IO. It takes care of the details and provides these functions as one-liners.

Comment: From where did you get the 8K limit from? It would help if you can share your code.

Comment: The default buffer size of some IO writers is 8k. The way you're using your code seems off a little. It would help tremendously if you posted the code you're attempting to use to write the file.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for certain without any code, but your limit probably isn't in the strings themselves. It's probably in the output buffer you're using to write it to disk. I bet you're not flushing the buffer very often, so as you write to it, the buffer fills up. Adding to a full buffer will drop any extra characters. I recommend flushing every once in a while.

Comment: Note that if you `close()` the FileOutputStream it will also flush it. So you probably forgot to close it.

Comment: @thilo I'm guessing he closed it, and it flushed the first 8k on close, the other 4k getting dropped because it never made it in the buffer.